# Defining new post image (not post thumbnail) sizes in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a total newbie to WordPress development and as far as it goes now, I understand that WP can create responsive images for me with a built in plugin since version 4.4.

In my project, I have two types of images. By types I mean their width.
First one, the widest one is 633px (which is double the size for Retina displays), and I set it as a "Large" in settings -> media -> Large size. So, whenever I upload this one, it works just fine, cause the medium size is also preset.

The problem occurs with the second type of images. They are much narrower, and I need a preset of width for them, which I have to implement in functions.php. The width for "Large" is 612px, and for "Medium" 306px.

What kind of filter should I add in function.php to implement those new sizes in my admin Dashboard, so WP will spit out those photos in appropriate size?

Thanks ahead everyone!

PS - solution is found!

```
    //Adding new img sizes
add_image_size( 'Portfolio-medium-wide', 633 );
add_image_size( 'Portfolio-large-wide', 1266 );
add_image_size( 'Portfolio-medium', 306 );
add_image_size( 'Portfolio-large', 612 );
add_image_size( 'Blog-medium', 469 );
add_image_size( 'Blog-large', 938 );

add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose','my_image_sizes' );

function my_image_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge ( $sizes, array(
        'Portfolio-medium-wide' => __('Portfolio Medium wide'),
        'Portfolio-large-wide' => __('Portfolio Large wide'),
        'Portfolio-medium' => __('Portfolio Medium'),
        'Portfolio-large' => __('Portfolio Large'),
        'Blog-medium' => __('Blog Medium'),
        'Blog-large' => __('Blog large'),
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use **add_image_size** function, please find the example below :

```
   // defining size in functions.php
    add_image_size( 'your_image_size', 370, 223,true);

   //using the size in other pages 
   the_post_thumbnail('your_image_size');
```

Hope it helps

Comment: You may need to regenerate the existing images using any plugins, for the new one it will work good.

Comment: Thanks bud! I found this somewhere in the internet. I will mark your reply as a proper one and add my code below as well.